# How to make skaffold dev skip building image entirely?

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Is there a way to make `skaffold dev` completely skip image building including the initial one? I have a prebuilt image. All I want skaffold to do is deploy the K8s Deployment YAML file and sync local files to it. I couldn't find a working example of how to do this. Closest was [this one](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/main/examples/hot-reload) but it assumes an initial image build.

`skaffold dev --auto-build=false` stills builds.

my `skaffold.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta26
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: gcr.io/my-project/my-repo
    context: .
    sync:
      infer: ["**/*"]
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - skaffold/*.yaml
```

```
skaffold dev --auto-build=false --default-repo gcr.io/my-project

Listing files to watch...
 - gcr.io/my-project/my-repo
Generating tags...
 - gcr.io/my-project/my-repo -> gcr.io/my-project/my-repo:v0.7.4-182-gb47cd3b5-dirty
Checking cache...
 - gcr.io/my-project/my-repo: Not found. Building
Starting build...
Building [gcr.io/my-project/my-repo]...
```

Update: Using skaffold v1.35.0 on an Ubuntu VM, deploying to remote GKE cluster version 1.20.10-gke.1600 created via Google Cloud Console. Storing images in Google Container Registry (gcr.io).

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skaffold's `build.local.tryImportMissing: true` setting will cause Skaffold to use a tagged image if it already exists.  In your example above, Skaffold would look for `gcr.io/my-project/my-repo:v0.7.4-182-gb47cd3b5-dirty`.

You could combine `tryImportMissing` with `skaffold dev --tag {fixed-tag}` argument to override the tagging policy to specify a fixed tag.

And `skaffold dev` also supports `--auto-build=false --auto-deploy=false` to avoid re-building and re-deploying changed images.

Comment: Thanks! adding `tryImportMissing` and `--tag` worked! Not sure why `--auto-build=false` didn't in my original approach though.

Comment: I noticed `skaffold` still expects a Dockerfile relative to `build.artifacts[].context` though. Is there a way to not require that or a local Docker daemon?

Comment: Skaffold defaults to treating an artifact as a docker build.  You can specify a different builder, such as a custom builder.

Comment: yup! This is the final thing I came up with https://github.com/davidxia/skaffold-no-docker-just-sync